# Recover vokoscreen screencast

Tags: 18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I was recording a Vokoscreen screencast when my computer unexpectedly crashed. Is there any way to recover the screencast? I don't see the video in the /Home/[USER]/Videos folder.

Thank you,

James Pedersen

Answer (score 0):

Open vokoscreenNG and check if the application prompts you to restore the screencast that you were recording when your computer unexpectedly crashed. If not, then the screencast is lost, and the easiest thing for you to do would be to record the screencast again.